# How to use referenced array and append more in YAML

Tags: yaml

I have this YAML snippet:

```yaml
plugins: &plugins
  - myplugin/master: ~
  - myplugin-2/master:
      - more: ~


table:
  plugins:
    - *plugins # This is nested instead of merged
    - additional_element: ~
```

### Actual:

Plugins referenced array is not merged instead they are appended as nested array (array of array)

Demo: [here](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=plugins%3A%20%26plugins%0A%20%20-%20myplugin%2Fmaster%3A%20%7E%0A%20%20-%20myplugin-2%2Fmaster%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20more%3A%20%7E%0A%0A%0Atable%3A%0A%20%20plugins%3A%0A%20%20%20%20-%20*plugins%20%23%20This%20is%20nested%20instead%20of%20merged%0A%20%20%20%20-%20additional_element%3A%20%7E&type=canonical_yaml)

### Expected Output:

```yaml
table:
  plugins:
    - myplugin/master: ~
    - myplugin-2/master:
      - more: ~
    - additional_element: ~
```

I simply want to get all plugin elements and add more to them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems i can do without dashes:

```yaml
table:
  plugins:
    <<: *plugins
    additional_element: ~
    # or more...
```